# How to evaluate expressions that are the column values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a big dataframe with millions of rows as follows:

```
A    B    C    Eqn
12   3    4    A+B
32   8    9    B*C
56   12   2    A+B*C
```

How to evaluate the expressions in the `Eqn` column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a custom UDF that evaluates these arithmetic functions

```
def evalUDF = udf((a:Int, b:Int, c:Int, eqn:String) => {
 val eqnParts = eqn
    .replace("A", a.toString)
    .replace("B", b.toString)
    .replace("C", c.toString)
    .split("""\b""")
    .toList

  val (sum, _) = eqnParts.tail.foldLeft((eqnParts.head.toInt, "")){
    case ((runningTotal, "+"), num) => (runningTotal + num.toInt, "") 
    case ((runningTotal, "-"), num) => (runningTotal - num.toInt, "") 
    case ((runningTotal, "*"), num) => (runningTotal * num.toInt, "") 
    case ((runningTotal, _), op) => (runningTotal, op)
  }

  sum
})

evalDf
  .withColumn("eval", evalUDF('A, 'B, 'C, 'Eqn))
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+-----+----+
|  A|  B|  C|  Eqn|eval|
+---+---+---+-----+----+
| 12|  3|  4|  A+B|  15|
| 32|  8|  9|  B*C|  72|
| 56| 12|  2|A+B*C| 136|
+---+---+---+-----+----+
```

As you can see this works, but is very fragile (spaces, unknown operators, etc will break the code) and doesn't adhere to order of operations (otherwise the last should have been 92)

So you could write all that yourself or find some library that already does that perhaps (like https://gist.github.com/daixque/1610753)?

Maybe the performance overhead will be very large (especially it you start using recursive parsers), But at least you can perform it on a dataframe instead of collecting it first

Comment: I would suggest using the Shunting Yard Algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) if the formulas can be more complex than what is shown here, but I agree that the UDF is inevitably the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way to execute SQLs that are inside a DataFrame is to `select("Eqn").collect` first followed by executing the SQLs iteratively on the source Dataset.

Since the SQLs are in a DataFrame that is nothing else but a description of a distributed computation that will be executed on Spark executors there is no way you could submit Spark jobs while processing the SQLs on executors. It is simply too late in the execution pipeline. You should be back on the driver to be able to submit new Spark jobs, say to execute SQLs.

With SQLs on the driver you'd then take the corresponding row per SQL and simply `withColumn` to execute SQLs (with their rows).

I think it's easier to write it than develop a working Spark application, but that's how I'd go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I am late But incase someone is looking for

- Generic Math expression interpreter using variables
- Complex/unknown expression that cannot be hardcoded into the UDF (accepted answer)

Then you can use `javax.script.ScriptEngineManager`

```
import javax.script.SimpleBindings;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager
import java.util.Map
import java.util.HashMap


def calculateFunction = (mathExpression: String, A : Double, B : Double, C : Double ) => {
    val vars: Map[String, Object] = new HashMap[String, Object]();
    vars.put("A",A.asInstanceOf[Object])
    vars.put("B",B.asInstanceOf[Object])
    vars.put("C",C.asInstanceOf[Object])
    val engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("js");
    val result = engine.eval(mathExpression, new SimpleBindings(vars));
    result.asInstanceOf[Double]
}

val calculateUDF = spark.udf.register("calculateFunction",calculateFunction)
```

**NOTE :** This will handle generic expressions and is robust but it give a **lot more worse performance** than the accepted answer and **heavy on memory**.